# add UiPickerView into AlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uipickerview

I am trying to create an alert message with built in UIPickerView in swift.

After pressing the button "test" Picker should appear in alert window:
[image]

The problem is only with data source for UIPickerView. It is empty:
[image]

The project is published in my [GIT](https://github.com/almazini/PickerTest) repo. Can somebody advice on how to fix it? 
Many thanks!

Comment: Please don't post a link to your code.  One of the Off-Topic close reasons says "Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this code working?) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem in the question itself.**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @NobodyNada Hi! thanks for your comment! I was trying to make it shorter. I have created separate project and removed all formatting. Will try better next time!

Comment: hey @Almazini i can't found git repo , plz share code i am also trying to do the same :) m new in ios so tx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your createContainerView function assign yourself as the delegate as follows:

```
self.currPicker.dataSource = self
self.currPicker.delegate = self
```